# Avoid page scrolling to the top when sap.m.Dialog appears

Tags: sapui5

I have a button on the buttom of the page that opens a dialog when pressed.
When the dialog appears the page automatically scrolls to the top.
Does anybody know how avoid that? I also wanted to ask how to center the text in the dialog content.

Thank you.

My code:

```
var oDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
icon: "sap-icon://hint",
showHeader: true,
content: new sap.m.Text({
text: "Are you sure you want to navigate away?"
}),
  buttons: [new sap.m.Button({
  text: "OK",
  press: function() {
    fNav()
    oDialog.close()
  }
}),
new sap.m.Button({
  text: "CANCEL",
  press: function() {
    oDialog.close()
   }
 })
],
})
```

Print screen of dialog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeqwq.jpg

Comment: There must be some explicite command in your app to scroll to the top before navigating. I don't think it's a normal behavior of UI5. What do you get if you enter `sap.ui.version` in the browser console during runtime?

Comment: Hello, I am using 1.38.9.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal code with which we can reproduce the scrolling behavior.